# Why is the resulting UV map stretched out when unwrapping my object?

Tags: uv

So, I've been unwrapping semi-circular objects and this happens:

[image: bolt_uv]

I wanted to know if it is a configuration setting that I'm screwing up or something like that. I can edit it but it is a huge pain, in some tutorials they just work. This is killing me slowly and surely.

[image]

Comment: how did you unwrap it? what option?

Comment: The unwrap option, no smart, spherical or nothing. Its a simple object :C, I only added 3 seams

Comment: perhaps share your file so that we can test

Comment: It looks like if your normals are flipped. With everything selected try Ctrl-N and Unwrap it again.

Comment: I tried flipping, did'nt work :c, i will try to share my file

Comment: Just tried unpinning too, didnt work as well. I'm beggining to feel that blender hates me here :<

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5121" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5121/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is:

In Object Mode: Apply the scale first.

Now you can unwrap it.

See the image below:

[image]

Edit: It is a good practice to Apply any transformations (scale, rotaion...)before using any modifier or/and Unwrap.

Comment: Oh my gawd, thank you so much, man! Now I will always keep that in my ocd checklist. You guys are freaking fast. I was aways afraid of seeking help in forums, but I loved it. Thanks to everyone again <3

Comment: You need to choose one of these answers.

Comment: I think what LeoNas means is that if one of these answers has solved your question, you can 'accept' it. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

When I try and unwrap your model a message appears in my toolbar:

[image]

And when looking at your object's dimensions, I see, as the previous message indicated, that your object has non-uniform scale (not all values are '1'), meaning the object has been scaled in object mode:

[image]

The unwrap operation works on the vertices, essentialy ignoring any scaling  in object mode you have done to the object (as I understand it). You need to 'apply' the scaling you did in object mode, to the underlying vertices. You can do this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and choosing *Scale*.

See [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data) for more information.

Comment: Wow, I also never noticed error messages in blender, now I look for them, and aways apply transformation changes :D. Thank you very much.